# Cant access form ele on callback OnSuccess from Ajax.beginform using $('this')

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in a view, inside a foreach loop for an IEnumerable:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PoolDelta", "Characters", 
                       new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               HttpMethod = "Get",
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               UpdateTargetId = crName,                                                
                               OnSuccess = "clearVal()"
                           }))
{
    <form id="@(crName)Form" name="@(crName)Form">
        <fieldset>
            @Html.Hidden("Id",item.CharacterId)
            @Html.Hidden("crNumber", "cr" + item.AssociatedLevel)
            @Html.Hidden("poolName", pnameNoSpace)
            @Html.Hidden("charName",  item.Character.Name)
            @Html.Hidden("crTextBoxName", crName)

            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="number" name="poolDelta" id=@pnameNoSpace />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="submit" name="crButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Use">
            </div>   
        </fieldset>
    </form>
}
```

I would like to do something like this for the OnSuccess callback:

```
 clearVal = function () {
    $('this').find('input[name=poolDelta]').val(''); 
        }
```

However 'this' doesn't refer to the form like I thought it would. Doing some research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756248/how-to-get-the-form-or-div-by-name-which-the-ajax-beginform-onsuccess-is-called) I see 'this' now refers to the XHR which I am unfamiliar with.

I cannot hardcode an id for the input because this is used in a list generated dynamically. I can't just shove the JS near the form because it's inside a table. Outside the table  I lose scope on any c# names (like @pnameNoSpace which is what I was trying to use)

Is there some other way for the OnSuccess callback to somehow get to it's associated form? or to the closest input given some attribute besides id?

By the way, everything else works perfectly. The Ajax replaces its target, OnSuccess fires if I test it with `alert()`, everything is good except I want to clear the text input after its submitted. I would consider a `.click()` function, but again I don't know how to do that when I can't reference the input by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** Inside the success callback, `this` refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to. [Learn more about how this works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

**Solution:**  you can save `this` object in a variable before making ajax request. Example like below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PoolDelta", "Characters", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = crName,                                                
    OnSuccess = clearVal(this)
}))
{
    <form id="@(crName)Form" name="@(crName)Form">
        <fieldset>
            @Html.Hidden("Id",item.CharacterId)
            @Html.Hidden("crNumber", "cr" + item.AssociatedLevel)
            @Html.Hidden("poolName", pnameNoSpace)
            @Html.Hidden("charName",  item.Character.Name)
            @Html.Hidden("crTextBoxName", crName)
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="number" name="poolDelta" id=@pnameNoSpace />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="submit" name="crButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Use">
            </div>   
        </fieldset>
    </form>
}

clearVal = function (obj) {
  $(obj).find('input[name=poolDelta]').val(''); 
}
```

Comment: Can I do that inside an mvc Ajax.beginform or do I have to use raw ajax?

Comment: Actually if this works the way I think it does, I would have to call a function using a click event on the button submit, but that suffers from the same problems I've been having: referencing the form with a unique id. So it won't work.

Comment: updated my answer, make sure to replace ajax option code to call `OnSuccess = clearVal(this)` with `this` object to refer the same inside `clearVal` function like `$(obj).find('input[name=poolDelta]').val(''); `

Comment: Ok yes that works Mahesh thx although I ended up finding a slightly different approach. I can pass the input id (@pnameNoSpace) as a parameter like this OnSuccess = "ClearVal(" + @pnameNoSpace + ")". Then my JS becomes function ClearVal(param) { 
        $("#" + param.id).val('');                      
    }; In the end it comes down to passing a parameter but I think I feel better referencing the actual id.

Comment: yes exactly either pass `this` object or pass `id` directly, Glad it works :)